# EOF and free part of unused 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

My background is java so I'm not used to c syntax yet.

I need to do the following: let the user to input number `k` (number of rows), and after to insert values into 2d array with this form:

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

i.e two values with space between them and then new line for the new row.
If the user entered `k=1000` but entered only `4` rows so the function call would be only with the array with 4 rows and not 100. the loop that reads the values should stop if: there are k rows **or** reaching to EOF

My questions:

1. I don't know how to implement the EOF part.
2. I don't know how to implement that for k=1000 and there only 4 rows so call the function with the array that contains only 4 rows

Here my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COLS 2
void foo(int** rows, int n);
int main()
{

    int k;
    printf("Please enter number of rows\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);

    int** matrix = (int**)malloc(k * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));

    int num1, num2;
    for (int i = 0; i < k||num1!=EOF; i++)
    {

        printf("Enter two numbers separated by space \n");
        scanf_s("%d  %d", &num1, &num2);
        matrix[i][0]=num1;
        matrix[i][1] = num2;
    }

    printf("The array:: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    foo(matrix, k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int** rows, int n)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Comment: You can check the value returned by [`scanf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf): _Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned._

Comment: Specifically, check that it equals the number of values you expect. `if(scanf_s("%d  %d", &num1, &num2) != 2) { break; }`

Comment: `int num1, num2; for (int i = 0; i < k||num1!=EOF; i++)`  note that `num1` is being used before it's initialized.  The comments above tell you how to address though.

Comment: FYI: When reading files EOF is read automatically. If you use the terminal you can provide an EOF by pressing CTRL+D in most Linux terminals. I have no experience within Windows with EOF.

Comment: Upvoted for moving away from Java and to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the bellow portion of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k||num1!=EOF; i++)
{

    printf("Enter two numbers separated by space \n");
    scanf_s("%d  %d", &num1, &num2);
    matrix[i][0]=num1;
    matrix[i][1] = num2;
}
```

To:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{

    printf("Enter two numbers separated by space \n");
    if(2 !=  scanf_s("%d  %d", &num1, &num2)) break;
    matrix[i][0]=num1;
    matrix[i][1] = num2;
}
k = i;
```

Hope it will work as you want

Comment: how do I get the eof to occuer, what should be the user's input

Comment: press "Ctrl+z" then press "enter" to occur EOF

Answer (score 0):

check the return value of scanf

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    printf("Enter two numbers separated by space \n");
    if(scanf_s("%d  %d", &num1, &num2)==EOF)
        break;
    matrix[i][0]=num1;
    matrix[i][1] = num2;
}
```

Comment: how do I get the eof to occuer, what should be the user's input

Comment: @SandeepPolamuri what will happen here when the user enters `1 a`?